# pyspark udf that counts when condition is satified

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Problem: I have a pyspark dataframe, which I want to summarize by columns and come up with a count for each ID, meeting a certain conditions. My dataset looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'ID': {0: u'00319383',
  1: u'00337642',
  2: u'0346945',
  3: u'00400193',
  4: u'00405079',
  5: u'0426407',
  6: u'00445573',
  7: u'00485834',
  8: u'0493307',
  9: u'00501281'},
 'type_A': {0: u'A',
  1: u'A',
  2: u'A',
  3: u'A',
  4: u'A',
  5: u'A',
  6: u'A',
  7: u'A',
  8: u'A',
  9: u'A'},
 'type_B': {0: u'None',
  1: u'B',
  2: u'None',
  3: u'None',
  4: u'None',
  5: u'None',
  6: u'None',
  7: u'None',
  8: u'B',
  9: u'None'},
 'type_C': {0: u'C',
  1: u'C',
  2: u'C',
  3: u'C',
  4: u'C',
  5: u'C',
  6: u'C',
  7: u'C',
  8: u'C',
  9: u'C'},
 'type_D': {0: u'None',
  1: u'None',
  2: u'None',
  3: u'None',
  4: u'None',
  5: u'None',
  6: u'None',
  7: u'D',
  8: u'None',
  9: u'None'}}
```

The goal is to count the occurrence of a product by ID. I developed a solution in SQL, which does what I want:

```
spark.sql('''
            select total, count(contract_id) as freq
            from 
            (
                select id, (typeA + typeB + typeC + typeD) as total
                from
                    (
                        select id
                        , case when type_A = 'A' then 1 else 0 end as typeA
                        , case when type_B = 'B' then 1 else 0 end as typeB 
                        , case when type_C = 'C' then 1 else 0 end as typeC  
                        , case when type_D = 'D' then 1 else 0 end as typeD  
                        from df 
                    ) a
            ) b

            group by total

         ''').toPandas()
```

How could I have done this with python/pyspark function? Looking for ideas for approaching such a problem?

Comment: What are the conditions you have in mind though? It does seem like a pretty simple ```df.groupBy("total").count()``` thing?

Comment: Conditions like type_A = 'A'. I'm basically trying to see how someone could implement that sql query as a python/pyspark function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then this should do the trick:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(
    (when(col("type_A") == lit("A"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))+
    when(col("type_B") == lit("B"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))+
    when(col("type_C") == lit("C"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))+
    when(col("type_D") == lit("D"), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0))).alias("total"), col("id")
).groupBy("total").agg(count(col("id")).alias("freq"))
```

Comment: So if you have 10 columns, you have to repeat the aggregation ten times? Once for each column?

Comment: No, you can put as many aggregating functions in ```.agg(...)``` as you wish. Same goes for ```.groupBy(...)``` (e.g. ```df.groupBy("total", "someOtherCol",...)...```) see my answer - I added more letters in the ```.agg(...)```

Comment: Ok I tried you idea, and I don't get anything close to what that SQL did.

Comment: Right, because you get only the most inner query. You want to translate the whole thing? Give me 10 mins

Comment: Try it now. IIUC that's the whole thing (you mix id-s in your query - ```id``` and ```contract_id```)